# Virtual Host, works but any links get instant 404 error message

Tags: linux, apache, localhost

I created and setup a LAMP stack, inserted the database + files + code, and went to the local host. The main page pulls up (GOOD!) but, any links on the main page, no matter what it is.. gives me this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /user/register was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at cbirc.com Port 80
```

I am assuming this is a apache issue? If someone could fill me in. Its strange that the main page pulls up fine, but any links to any other part of the site gives me this error code.

Answer (score 0):

If index is working, It sound that RewriteEngine was not set to ON in apache configuration, Try to add this to your .htaccess file or vhost (/etc/apache2/sites-available/yourdomaine.com) :

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
</ifModule>
```

If you modify vhost, don't forget to restart apache :

```
sudo apachectl configtest #Test before restart
sudo apachectl restart
```

if module is not installed :

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

You can also check the Base URL in your HTML if you have one